# Scalars by which symmetrizations of cyclic permutations act on Specht modules

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group. Pick $a \in 2,\ldots,n$ and denote by $c_a \in \mathbb{C}[S_n]$ the symmetrization of the element $(12\ldots a)$ i.e. $c_a$ is the sum of cycles of type $a$.

Let $\lambda$ be a Young diagram of size $n$ and denote by $V_\lambda$ the corresponding Specht module (irreducible representation of $S_n$ corresponding to $\lambda$).

Since $c_a \in \mathbb{C}[S_n]$ is central it must act on $V_{\lambda}$ by some scalar $c_a(\lambda)$.

Question: are there any “simple” formulas for these scalars $c_a(\lambda)$? Equivalently one may ask if there are “simple” formulas that present elements $c_a$ as symmetric functions on Jucys Murphy elements?

Comment: Up to multiplying by the number of a-cycles and dividing by the dimension of the Specht module isn't this just asking for the character value on a?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! So we can try to compute these numbers using the Frobenius character formula.